# Studying dynamic elasticity for finite deformations

Tags: classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, elasticity, stress-strain, non-linear-systems

this is not a question asking for help with a problem but one asking for help where to begin serious study of elasticity, particularly that applied to dynamic systems. Most textbooks about elasticity focus on strain and stress and mention little about how position and energy evolve with time; my interest lies chiefly in looking at how elastic rods, rings etc. respond to a deformation. I was wondering where I should begin in terms of material like textbooks, online lecture series for this.

I have looked extensively and found scores of books and websites that are useful for static elasticity but preferably, as an undergraduate physicist I'd like an introduction like, perhaps, Landau & Lifshitz classical mechanics book.

Comment: You need to solve the rheological equation for the elastic material in conjunction with the differential stress-equilibrium equation, including the dynamic inertial terms.  Books on fluid mechanics routinely combine the dynamic stress-equilibrium equation with the rheological equation for a Newtonian fluid to obtain the Navier Stokes equations.

Comment: If this is part of your undergraduate studies, have you asked your lecturer or course tutor?  The department or university librarian?  The Mech Eng department?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that a good point to start are decent introductory books about continuum mechanics in general to get an idea about how the framework works in general and how systems are described, how different quantities are transported. For this I myself really liked as a starting point:

Liu, Continuum Mechanics, Berlin, Heidelberg: Springer, 2002

It is by far not the most complete account, but it is a nice, well motivated, good to read introduction which gives you the basic concepts.

For further reading, I myself like:

Haupt, Continuum Mechanics and Theory of Materials, Berlin Heidelberg: Springer,
2000

It is, for my taste, a bit less clear and concise, but the extent is quite superior to Liu's book and I always found it useful for looking up things that were not covered adequatly in Liu's work.

Finally, if you have a lot of time to invest, I personally suggest you

Marsden und Hughes, Mathematical Foundations of Elasticity, Mineola: Dover
Publications, 1994

This book is very mathematical but it is, in my opinion, worth it and even by only reading the first chapters you will get a very, very solid basis for the underlying mathematics.

If you understand the framework of continuum mechanics itself, I think the question of which material you actually have can be more easily adressed and understood. I am personally not working on Elasticity, so I unfortunately cannot give you any specific works for that, but as the response to your question seemed pretty low, I thought it was a good idea to still post my recommendations.

Comment: Apologies for not responding until now. These suggestions are immensely helpful and I've already begun looking at the Marsden and Hughes book and it seems like what I'm looking for. I have a couple of questions about some of the things in it if you think you might be able to answer them.

Comment: I'm happy you find it helpful. Post the questions with the quotation onto Physics Stack Exchange and I'll promise you to have a look whether I know something helpful. I did however not study the whole book.